# Caching Data vs. Multiple Queries

Tags: java, database

Very broad & open question concerning performance & implementation here:

**The Program**

I've built a program that allows a user to import an excel spreadsheet that contains a username and email address. This spreadsheet can have up to 100,000 unique records.

**The Requirement**

The requirement of this program is to check for duplicates in the database in order to prevent saving the same user twice

**The Issue**

The issue I anticipate running into is performance when it comes to checking for duplicates - I am looking for the fastest/most efficient method of validating unique users (based on the name and email address).

My first solution was to cache all existing members into a `HashMap` upon import, this way I can traverse the Map and compare my records being uploaded one by one. The obvious Pro here is one single database call - however if my Database has one million users stored I assume this may crash or severely lag my application.

The second solution was to call the database per each record to see if the username/email already exist. I'm not sure if this is desirable because 50,000 users would equal 50,000 database calls - doesn't sound too good to me.

Is there a preferred solution over the two listed above, or any aspect of this task I'm not taking into consideration here? (Batching, Database query patterns, etc).

Any input is appreciated, thank you!

Note * I'm using a SQL Server database (even though I'd like to be database agnostic, I'm open to any SQL recommendations)

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports such a feature you could use a `MERGE` statement or a `INSERT IGNORE` so that all duplicate records are silently discarded and you can skip the test if the record already exists.

MERGE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29
MySQL INSERT IGNORE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

Add constraint UNIQUE to email and username columns.
If you want to update on duplicates use UPSERT syntax that your database supports

Comment: Right, I'd put in a Unique constraint of course, but what if the 99,999th record of the 100,000 was found to be a duplicate? The program would still have to traverse all of the records before it discovered the dupe. I'm focusing on the best method for performance while checking, not the actual duplicate check method itself

Comment: if it is duplicate it won't be saved. Or you want to insert all rows by one batch? If you want to update on duplicates use UPSERT syntax that your database supports